# Javascript change label text only

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="here_is_div">
    <label class="a_label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
            Hello world
    </label>
</div>
```

I thought `textContent` would be able to just change the `TEXT`

```
document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].textContent = "Hello World is replaced"
```

However, `textContent` replaces everything including checkbox. Is there a better way to just change text without doing something like below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">Hello world is replaced';
```

Comment: Get the `textNode` child of the label and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to select the *text node* specifically.

```js
document.querySelector('label').childNodes[2].textContent = 'Hello World is replaced';
```

```html
<div class="here_is_div">
    <label class="a_label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
            Hello world
    </label>
</div>
```

Note that you have 3 child nodes of the `label` here: the whitespace and newline between the `label` and the `input`, the `input` itself, and the `Hello world` and surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text inside a **span** tag:

```js
document.querySelector('label span').textContent = 'Hello World is replaced';
```

```html
<div class="here_is_div">
    <label class="a_label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
            <span>Hello world</span>
    </label>
</div>
```